# How to query if any bit in a range is set in a C++ std::bitset?

Tags: c++, bitset

I am looking for a C++ bitset implementation that can answer if a bit is set in a range.  [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/), [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/), and [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) all give access to individual bits that I can loop over, but that isn't the most efficient way to query a range of bits to ask if *any* bit is set- I don't even need to know which one.

```
bitset b;
if(b.any(33, 199))
{
    // ...
}
```

Is there a library that provides this?  I would like to run some benchmarks against other implementations (including one I may have to write), but I can't find any that appear to implement this functionality.

Comment: Much more effocient is not to try use container but use Hamming code/popcount algorithms or intrinstic function. Most of bitsets don't use binary representation internally because they weren't meants for fast bit operations with data.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in  C++11 bitset it is not possible to set a range of bits to the given value by just specifying the boundaries of the range. Iterating over individual bits seems the most we can do. It is also not possible to check if all bits inside the range are set to the same value (1,0).

There is an open source project in Git that provides an alternative implementation of the BitSet ([RangedBitset](https://github.com/andviane/ranged_bitset)) that supports these operations. It uses an array of `uint_64t_` words of any size internally, but can also handle ranges specified with the accuracy of the single bit. There you can do the things like

```
 a.set(4, 8, true); // set the range [ 4 .. 8 [ to true
 bool is_all_range = a.check(2, 6, true); // check if all range is set to 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if some bit is set in the range [x,y] in bitset, you can use `bs._Find_next(x-1)`. It returns the next set bit after the position x-1.
Then you can check if the returned value is <=y or not.

```
bool Find_if_bitset_has_any_set_bit_in_range(bitset<M> &bs, int x, int y){
   if(bs._Find_next(x-1)<=y)   return 1;   //TRUE
   return 0;                               //FALSE
}
```

Comment: `_Find_next` isn't in C++ standard https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

Comment: It works with ``#include<bits/stdc++.h> `` on my PC. I am not very sure which specific standard C++ library is it associated to. You can refer this for more information on its implementation. [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00775_source.html)

Comment: [`_` followed by an uppercase character are reserved names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/995714), which means this is some **extension** in some C++ STL implementations like libstdc++ but it's not standard C++ where STL names are always in lowercase. Did you see the link above? It's clear that that method isn't available in any C++ versions

Comment: And it's in `<bitset>`, not `<bits/stdc++.h>`. See [Why should I not #include `<bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714) . See also [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Answer (score -1):

C++11's bitset provides the any() method that you are after, but if that isn't an option then just use b.to_ulong() and check for non zero.

Comment: Can you provide a link?  I see an `any()` in the reference, but not one based on a range of bits.

Comment: std::bitset::any(): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/all_any_none, you are using C++11, right?

Comment: I can use c++11, but I don't think the `any()` you linked to supports **ranges**.  I.e. it cannot answer the question "is any bit in the range [x,y] set?".